# How can I fix the 'received unexpected message' error in my RSpec test for setting up a chess game?

Tags: rspec

I'm using rspec to test my code and I receive this error:

- Failure/Error: board.square_collection = board.create_board
  #<InstanceDouble(Board) (anonymous)> received unexpected message :square_collection= with (nil)

Does anyone know how to fix it? Thank you very much.

This is my code:

```
def set_up 
        board.square_collection = board.create_board
        [white, black].each do |player|
            player.pieces.each do |piece|
                board.get_square(piece.position).status = piece
            end
        end
    end

describe "#set_up" do 
        let(:board) { instance_double(Board) }
        let(:white) { instance_double(Player) }
        let(:black) { instance_double(Player) }
        let(:square) { instance_double(Square) }
        let(:pawn) { instance_double(Pawn) }
        before do 
            
            allow(board).to receive(:square_collection)
            allow(board).to receive(:create_board)
            allow(white).to receive(:pieces).and_return([pawn, pawn, pawn])
            allow(black).to receive(:pieces).and_return([pawn, pawn, pawn])
            allow(pawn).to receive(:position)
            allow(board).to receive(:get_square).and_return(square)
            allow(square).to receive(:status)
            game.board = board
            game.white = white
            game.black = black
        end
        it "get_square is called n times with n=total pieces of two player" do
            expect(board).to receive(:get_square).exactly(6).times 
            game.set_up
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your method, `board.square_collection =` is called, but in your test `board` stubbed to `receive(:square_collection)`.

Change

```
allow(board).to receive(:square_collection)
```

to

```
allow(board).to receive(:square_collection=)
```

And you will need to do the same for this line

```
allow(square).to receive(:status)
```

which needs to change to

```
allow(square).to receive(:status=)
```